# How to search data in object and cast to list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to search value from object and convert result to list

I tried to get data object name "data" and i want to search every item that has "querytext".How to convert object data to List

```
public class SimpleMovieSearchService implements MovieSearchService {
   @Autowired
   private MovieDataService movieDataService;

   @Override
   public List<Movie> search(String queryText) {
   MoviesResponse data =movieDataService.fetchAll();
       List<Movie> result = data.stream() // problem in this line 
            .filter(item -> item.getTitle().equals("queryText"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return result;
   }
}
```

**MovieData.java**

```
public class MovieData {
   private String title;
   private int year;
   private List<String> cast;
   private List<String> genres;

   getter and setter
}
```

**Movie.java**

```
public class Movie {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<String> actors = new ArrayList<>();

 getter and setter
}
```

**edit**

**MovieResponse.java**

```
public class MoviesResponse extends ArrayList<MovieData> {
}
```

**MovieDataService.java**

```
public interface MovieDataService {
  MoviesResponse fetchAll();
}
```

Type of data i got is List of MovieData but i want result in List of Movie how to fix this or another way to do.and without change anything in *Movie.java* or *MovieData.java*

## Update

now i can do with this way

```
MoviesResponse a = movieDataService.fetchAll();
    List<Movie> result = a.stream()
            .map(movie -> new Movie(movie.getTitle()))
            .filter(movie -> movie.getName().equals(queryText)) //this line
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if data are "banana" ,"nature" , "red" and then query text is "na" i want result are "banana" and "nature".in sql in situation it can use "like".How to use "like" with this filter ?

Comment: Please post your MoviesResponse and your MovieDataService class too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use stream map

```
data.stream() // problem in this line 
        .filter(item -> item.getTitle().equals("queryText"))
        .map(movie -> {
        //logic to transform MovieResponse in Movie here
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

See more in: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-map-filter-collect-of-stream-in-java-8

Comment: Thank you.But i got a little question.If i want operator like "like" in sql what i should put in stead " .equals "

Comment: You can use the .contains method of String.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching all movies and filer them by stream, write a method that queries the ones you want.

Something like

`SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title = 'queryText'`

Depending on your code/framework, you have to implement this or just have to choose another method in you MovieDataService.

Comment: I want to but This subject is use object from method fetchAll() and search value in object with "querytext" and then contain to List<Movie> for return List